# Extern access to a Java EE webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

When developing a Java EE 7 webapp (Win8, eclipse Kepler, JBoss Tools 4.1.1, wildfly8.0CR) I can use the application at localhost:8080/app/
But I wonder what to do, if I want an extern access to that app, e.g. from my other PC. What configuration is needed, or do you need a "real" server for such a purpose?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You must use a server like glassfish,

Comment: Because its better than wildfly, or what? However, that doesnt help me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How public to you want your website to be?

If you want to access it from another computer on the same network(for example your home network) you need to adjust your network and firewall settings so that that you would have access from one computer to anoher on the same network. Then if on the computer that contains the app you would access it for example `http://localhost:8080/myapp` then on another network you would access it `http://ip-of-the-comuter-that-contains-the-app:8080/`.

If you would like to access it from outside the local network then the process is same, but a static IP would be recommended to the computer that contains the app.

If you would like the general public to use the app, then hosting it from your PC may not be such a good idea and somekind of server solution is adviseable. There are lots of different cloud solutions like http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/ or https://developers.google.com/appengine/ that would provide enough flexibility for majority of apps. Or you could ofcourse have your own server hardware, but this can turn out to be much more expensive to keep stable and secure.

Comment: Thanks much. That helped. I didnt search for a "final" solution anyway, I just searched for a temporary "test-solution" away from the eclipse-sandbox-development-view. Thank you for your links and answer.

Comment: @Martin It's could to know that i was of use to you. A good way to show in this environment that you appreciate someones answer is to upvote it or verify it as the correct one :)

Comment: Tarmo, I wanted to upvote you before, but it said I need a reputation of 15 to do so. However, the "Accepting the answer" works, that I didnt realize before.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick-and-dirty solution you can choose the "Enable remote access" option on the server (double click the server, and you should see a check box in the server editor).

This will tell the server to start listening on all network interfaces and not just the local one.

btw. we only listen on local network interface by default for security reasons since we don't want you to unintentionally get hacked if a vulnerability is found and used by someone malicious.